# Installation of Pyscopg2 Module not found

Tags: python, python-3.8

So I am trying to import pyscopg2 but each time I run the code I receive this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "demo.py", line 1, in
>
> import pyscopg2 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyscopg2'

I checked if I installed pyscopg2, after running `pip install psycopg2` and it displayed

> Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in
> c:\python38\lib\site-packages (2.9.3) WARNING: You are using pip
> version 19.2.3, however version 22.2.2 is available. You should
> consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip'
> command., below is an image of my code

[Image of my CMD which shows me running my code and the errors I recieved and the confirmation I had](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K21R8.png)

Below is also the code I am trying to run

```
import pyscopg2

connection = pyscopg2.connect('dbname= example')

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('''

CREATE table table2 (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    completed BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT False
);

''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True)

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table2 (id, completed) VALUES (1, true);')

connection.commit()

connection.close()

cursor.close()
```

**SUMMARY**
A summary of what have said is that whenever I run my code  which is demo.py with `python demo.py` I always get the error

> pyscopg2 module not found

.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You import pyscopg2, module name is psycopg2

Comment: Thanks it worked, but am having another issue because its requesting for password